# How to write a single spacebar to a txt file with batch

Tags: batch-file, echo

I need to add a single spacebar to a textfile ussing batch

however the following dosnt work

```
ECHO  >C:\txt.txt
```

this produces the text Echo is (off) instead???

Im ussing windows batch

Comment: Do you want the space to be ASCII or UNICODE? `0x20` or `0x20 0x00`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo` is printing the text "ECHO if off" because you haven't provided any parameters to it. If you type `echo /?` for usage instructions you will see this behavior defined: "Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting". So, in your case, echo is set to off.

If you want to have on the space character without a newline and carriage return you will most likely need to use `set`. If you are using Windows XP, this should be easy.

### Windows XP

```
>txt.txt ( <nul set /p "= " )
```

If you are running Vista or Higher it keeps a little tricky because windows strips leading spaces on the set command.

### Windows Vista or Higher

You will need to create a backspace character and then print that:

```
:: Create a backspace character
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set BS=%%A

<nul set /p=%BS% > txt.txt
```

Note that this doesn't actually print a space, but a backspace character instead. I'm not quite sure if this will work for you, but I couldn't think of any easier way. Otherwise you are probably better off using some other scripting language, like python or powershell.

Comment: +1 for XP but I think the backspace solution would actually write the backspace char follwed by a space to the file. The only other way I can think is the stupid `copy /b src.file + onewhitespacefile.txt src.file`

Comment: +1  Here is a full XP example: `>txt.txt ( <nul set /p "= " )`  Recommend placing quotations around the equals sign and space to prevent the space from being trimmed by certain text editors.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann using your example because it's more clear. I originally forgot to redirect it to a file as well.

Comment: I've posted a [solution for Vista and beyond](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19441398/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

1. Echo a space (+ line break)

   ```
   ECHO. > C:\txt.txt
   ```

   Note that this will output a *carriage return plus line break* (an enter) as well. So your  file will become 3 bytes.
2. Alternatively, you may create the file with a 0-byte using

   ```
   fsutil file createnew c:\txt.txt 1
   ```

   Only this doesn't add a space, but a 0 character.
3. Alternatively, you may create a file with a single space once, and copy that to `txt.txt` each time you need it to contain a space.
4. Use an external tool, like `echon.exe` from [this zipfile](http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/pc/link/tsbat.zip) ([from this site](http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd015.htm)). It mimics `echo -n`, like it is available in Linux.

Comment: I hate to be a pain but it needs to be without a line break (an enter). its because it writes a script file wich will become confused with the line break.

Comment: Alternative method to write a 0 character without an enter. Unfortunately this character is not a real space, so I don't know if your script accepts it. Proves to be quite hard to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Not only does SET /P not print leading white space on Vista and beyond, it also cannot print leading `=`.

Below is code that works on all modern versions of Windows from XP onward:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set EOL=%%A^


:: The above two empty lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE
<nul set /p "=x!EOL! " >temp.tmp
findstr /v $ temp.tmp >file.txt
del temp.tmp
```

The above technique can be extended to support printing nearly any string without newline, with a few exceptions:

- The string must not contain a carriage return
- XP FINDSTR will display most control characters and many extended ASCII characters as dots. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more info.

Comment: +1 Intersting new technic, do you can get it working with a pipe to findstr?

Comment: I get a zero byte `temp.tmp` file and an error from findstr - where does `ln.tmp` come into the picture?

Comment: @foxidrive - Thanks, all fixed. It was an artifact of changing the file name after testing the code, and forgetting to change it in one place.

Comment: @jeb - Unfortunately no, a pipe cannot work because FINDSTR appends `<CR><LF>` to piped input that does not end with `<LF>`.

Answer (score 2):

To create a single space with Win Vista or above you can't use the `SET/P` command anymore (as dbenham mentioned).

But you can use the `copy` command

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :createSub
call :echoWithoutLinefeed "=hello"
call :echoWithoutLinefeed " world"
exit /b

:echoWithoutLinefeed
> txt.tmp (echo(%~1!sub!)
copy txt.tmp /a txt2.tmp /b > nul
type txt2.tmp
del txt.tmp txt2.tmp
exit /b

:createSub
copy nul sub.tmp /a > nul
for /F %%a in (sub.tmp) DO (
   set "sub=%%a"
)
del sub.tmp
exit /b
```

First the text is outputs with a simple `ECHO` but at the end a `SUB` character is appended, just before the `ECHO` appends `CR LF`.

And with `copy inputfile /a outputfile /b` all characters are copied up to the first `SUB` character.

Comment: Just adding here that the `SUB` is also known in Windows as an EOF marker. (End Of File)

Comment: SUB, EOF, Ctrl-Z, 0x1A, decimal 26 - all the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods for 32 bit Windows:

This method creates a file directly with hex 20 (space):

```
@echo off
(for %%v in (E100''20 Nfile.tmp RCX 01 W Q) do @echo %%v)|debug >nul
ren file.tmp "file with a single space.txt"
```

This one removes the two trailing characters from the file.tmp file

```
@echo off
set f=file.tmp
echo. >%f%
(for %%v in (E100''83''E9''02 L103 P N%f% W103 Q) do echo %%v)|debug %f% >nul
ren %f% "file with a single space.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Vista and higher, any bitness.

```
@echo off
(
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
echo IA==
echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----
)>file.tmp
certutil -decode file.tmp "file with a single space.txt" >nul
del file.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to create a one byte single space file without creating a temporary file.

```
cmd /d /c (prompt=$S) ^& cmd /d /k <nul >SingleSpace.txt
```